# Ultimate user tracking list?

Tags: php, user-tracking

Is there a list of possible items we can track about users, both client and server side in php? I dont care so much about OS, brower, etc but more privacy items like wifi vs land, ssid, ipaddress, etc. There must be some ultimate list out there?

Answer (score 1):

> wifi vs land

no way you could track that

> ssid

Also not possible to track

> I dont care so much about OS, brower

That's what most users track.

> There must be some ultimate list out there?

Don't know, don't care. More then those simple ones could be privacy breaches(no consent)!

Comment: privacy breaches occur only if you track without user' consent. But if users opt-in then there is no breach. We can even sit in their house and record their life if they allow.